# Ubuntu 16.4: monodoc doesn't work (libgluezilla is missing)

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm new to mono and monodevelop.
I have Ubuntu 16.4 64-bit and installed both products as described on their respective websites.
The problem is: monodoc doesn't work.
It seems to depend on a package **libgluezilla**, which is not available anymore. (It's neither in the ubuntu nor in the mono package sources.) 
I am surprised that I did not find anything about this problem on the web (at least not in the monodoc context) although I assume that others have this problem, too.

On http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/webbrowser I read that libgluezilla is related to gecko, which is only one of several supported browser engines. So I tried:

```
$ monodoc --engine GtkHtml  
$ monodoc --engine WebKit
```

... (for all browser engines listed on the monodoc man page)
But in all cases monodoc complained about the missing libgluezilla.
Did you have this problem, too, and if yes, how did you handle it?
Do you just do without monodoc? (F1 seems not to work in monodevelop anyway. (In Visual Studio F1 launches the API browser for the currently selected class/method/....))

I do not really want to install any old .deb-archives, which might involve security issues.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/465542/install-libgluezilla-create-desktop-in-kubuntu-14-04/465593#465593

Comment: @Capricorn. Yes, I read it, but it's obviously outdated.  
libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil is already installed, but it doesn't contain libgluezilla.  
It "recommends" the package libgluezilla.  
libgluezilla is a "virtual package", but there are no concrete packages which "provide" it.  
  
I posted my question 20 hours ago and since then it got only 14 views.  
And in the monodevelop channel on irc.gimp.org there are also always only the same ten idlers.  
Do mono/monodevelop have such a small user base or am I just looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 0):

I never use F1 myself... it never worked for me. Instead, I use the [mono official documentation via web](http://docs.go-mono.com/).